# How to integrate $e^{-x^2 -y^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, error-function

How do you compute the following integral:$e^{-x^2 -y^2}$? Wolfram already gives the answer as: $\frac{1}{2}  \sqrt{\pi} e^{-y^2}  \text{erf}(x) + C$, but I have no idea how to get there. I tried using double integration, and all I ended up with $\frac{1}{4}xy * e^{(-x^2)-y^2}$.

[Wolfram Alpha Calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20e%5E%28%28-x%5E2%29%20-y%5E2%29)

Comment: Integrate WRT what?

Comment: Could you please clean up the formatting. It's not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: I thought the idea was to integrate with respect to both x and y, this being a double-integral. Maybe I've got the wrong idea? What about integrating WRT just X?

Comment: Your problem both here and (partially) with Wolfram Alpha is you are not clear about your variables of integration. Alpha appears to make a guess that you just want to integrate over $x$ (but if you add "dx dy" to tell it you want the double integral, I think you'll be disappointed). Look up the definition of erf$(x)$ (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) and you'll see why it shows up here.

Comment: Try this query to Wolfram Alpha: "integrate e^(-x^2-y^2) from x=-infinity to infinity and y=-infinity to infinity". Is that the question you are trying to ask? Of course Alpha doesn't tell you _how_ to show that this is the answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to integrate over both $x$ and $y$, then you can convert it to an integral in polar coordinates  $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\ dx \ dy=
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-r^2}\ r\ d\theta \ dr\\
=2\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-r^2}\ r \ dr\\=\pi\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-u}\ du$$

Comment: shouldn't the integral start from $0$ rather than $-\infty$ after you've made the change in polar coordinates?

Comment: @Ant: Yes, and I was fixing it.  Thanks

Comment: Despite all your explanation, I'm still lost as to how that becomes $\frac{1}{2}  \sqrt{\pi} e^{-y^2}$. I've been trying it a bunch on paper, and I still never reach that.

Comment: The double integral just becomes $\pi$, as you can see if you do the integral in my last line and get $1$.  In your original question, Alpha only integrated in $x$.  The $e^{-y^2}$ was treated as a constant. The $x$ integral gave you $\frac 12 \sqrt \pi \operatorname{erf}(x)$.  That comes from the definition of the error function.

Comment: OK, I got $pi$ as well, what I'm still unable to do is get from the original function to $\frac{1}{2}  \sqrt{\pi} e^{-y^2}$, even if I treat $e^{-y^2}$ as a constant.

Comment: The definition of the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) is $\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac 2{\sqrt \pi}\int_0^x e^{-x^2}dx$  The $\frac 12 \sqrt \pi$ come from there.  So $\int e^{-x^2-y^2}dx=e^{-y^2}\int e^{-x^2} dx =e^{-y^2} \frac {\sqrt \pi}2 \operatorname{erf}(x)$

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the *indefinite* integral with respect to both $x$ and $y$ because it does not make sense. Imagine finding a function $F(x,y)$ as an answer; then what are the properties you expect $F(x,y)$ to have? Since you cannot differentiate simultaneously with respect to $x$ and $y$, integrating with respect to two variables does not make sense.

Of course if you're talking about a *definite* integral things change, but you have to specify the domain on which you are integrating.

I'm going to make an educated guess and say that what you want is $$\int_{\mathbb R^2} e^{-x^2 - y^2} \ dx \ dy$$

It should be clear that this is a number and not a function.

To find the value of this integral you can make the usual substitution in polar coordinates to get

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} \rho e^{-\rho^2} \ d\theta \ d\rho  = 2\pi \int_0^\infty\rho e^{-\rho^2} \ d\rho$$

And I think you can conclude from here :)